# Create batch file for copy all the contained in root folder (including folder and files) to another folder

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file to test copy all the contain of the folder to another folder as below:

```
XCOPY /S /Y "C:\Windows\Source\1\*.*" "C:\Windows\Source\O365PP\Office\Data"
```

But, when i run it, It will never copy a single files from the source and the **cmd** screen was shown and won't disappear. Kindly advice.

Thank you

Comment: Basic check - do you have the correct folder paths? Permissions to access?

Comment: If you want to copy __all__ the files in one folder to another you should use `*.*` not `1*.*`.

Comment: You could also try to navigate to the destination, i.e., `cd` to `C:\Windows\Source\O365PP\Office\Data` then issue the same command without the destination, i.e., `XCOPY /S /Y "C:\Windows\Source\*.*"` Windows will know that the intended destination is the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll have to tell XCOPY if the destination is a File or Directory:

```
C:\Scripts>xcopy /s /y c:\Scripts\Test\*.* c:\scripts\mine
Does C:\scripts\mine specify a file name or directory name on the target
(F = file, D = directory)?
```

In this case, adding the switch `/I` would help.

```
/I           If destination does not exist and copying more than one file,
         assumes that destination must be a directory.
```

Also, double quotes are not needed UNLESS your filenames have a space.

@franklin is correct saying the destination needs the `\*.*`